# Please how do I share data from show method to two different views

Tags: laravel, methods, view, controller, share

Please I need to know if there is a way I can share data from one controller method to multiple views,

**This is the CategoryController show method**

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id);

    $users = $category->user;
  
    return view('categories.show')->with('users', $users);
}
```

what I want is to share the same data with another page profile-display.blade.php without creating another controller.

Comment: do you want to return to different view based on a condition?

Answer (score 1):

@Adam this will help you.

```
route.php

Route::get('users/{id}', 'CategoryController@show')->name('profile');

Route::get('Category/{id}', 'CategoryController@show')->name('category');

CategoryController.php

public

function show($request, $id) {
    $category = Category::find($id);

    $users = $category->user;
    if ($request::route()->getName() == 'category') {
        return view('categories.show')->with('users', $users);
    } else {
        return view('profile.show')->with('users', $users);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Qamar Rafhan but when I run the code I got an empty collection of data on view('profile.show')->with('users', $users);

Comment: You need to define Category Relationship with User in category model and make sure records are present in database

Answer (score 0):

Different routes can use the same controller, but you are going to have a harder time having a single controller present multiple views without a chaos of conditions or at least just make a new controller/method.

You can shave of some of your of your code to make a slimmer approach, though, by using model binding with routes:

`routes.php`

```php
Route::get('categories/{category}', 'CategoryController@show');
```

and then in `CategoryController.php`:

```php
public function show(Category $category)
{  
    return view('categories.show')->with('users', $category->user);
}
```

This will enable model binding to auto-instantiate the model if it exists and return a 404 if not.

You can reiterate the process for a second view, but just reuse the same controller (which I personally wouldn't prefer at all). Just add the route and the new method in the same controller:

`routes.php`

```php
Route::get('categories/{category}', 'CategoryController@show');
Route::get('profile-display', 'CategoryController@profileDisplay');
```

and then in `CategoryController.php`:

```php
public function show(Category $category)
{  
    return view('categories.show')->with('users', $category->user);
}

public function profileDisplay()
{  
    return view('profile-display');
}
```

I haven't added any model bindings to the `profileDisplay`method as I couldn't really understand how you would like to attache the category to a profile display page (as the name suggests), but that could give you some rough ideas.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::share('foo', 'bar');`